# Angular 11 nested subscription with if/else conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to optimize the following code.

But in the if/else statement, in the else part I need to run another subscription
and the key thing the last part

```
this.serviceB.checkState();
```

needs to run whenever everything has finished.

Can you point me in the right direction, please?

```
forkJoin([
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(take(1)),
  this.serviceA.selectedValue
]).pipe(
  tap(([paramMap, selectedValue]) => {
  const snapshot = this.route.snapshot;
  const categories = snapshot.params.categories;
  
  if (selectedValue && +selectedValue.id === +snapshot.params.selectedId) {
    ...
    this.isLoading = false;
    ...
    
    // no other observer needed
    

  } else {
      
    this.getByIdSub = this.serviceA.getById(this.route.snapshot.params.selectedId).subscribe(result => {         
    
      this.serviceA.setSelected(result).then(() => {
        ... 
        this.isLoading = false;
        ...
      });
      
      
    });
  }

}),
switchMap(r => {
  return this.serviceB.items.pipe(take(1),
    tap((items: Item[]) => {
        
      this.serviceB.checkState(); // <---- this must run after everything above is done
      
    })
  );
  
})
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an RxJs world, any time you have an if-then-else situation you should start thinking in terms of creating multiple streams with `filter` and then `merge` them back together again.

So, in this case, you could proceed like this.

First you create a stream that emits `selectedValue` and snapshot.params.selectedId`, which are the 2 things you use to evaluate the if condition.

```
const source$ = forkJoin([
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(take(1)),
  this.serviceA.selectedValue
]).pipe(
  tap(([paramMap, selectedValue]) => {
    const snapshot = this.route.snapshot;
    return [selectedValue, +snapshot.params.selectedId];
  }),
  // we add share so that the 2 downstream Observable will share the same subscription
  share()
)
```

Now that we have the upstream Observable, we can create 2 downstream Observables applying a `filter`

```
const sameAsSelectedId$ = source$.pipe(
  // this filter is equivalent to the if true condition
  filter(([selectedValue, selectedId]) => selectedValue && +selectedValue.id === selectedId),
  tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
)

const differentFromSelectedId$ = source$.pipe(
  // this filter is equivalent to the if false condition
  filter(([selectedValue, selectedId]) => selectedValue && +selectedValue.id !== selectedId),
  // use concatMap to concatenate the "execution" of the next Observable to the notification of 
  // something from the above filter
  concatMap(() => this.serviceB.items.pipe(
    take(1),
    tap((items: Item[]) => {  // bìnot sure what you do with items, anyways this is not the point
      this.serviceB.checkState();
    })
  )
)
```

Eventually you just merge the 2 downstream filtered Observables to return back to a single stream

```
const finalStream$ = merge([sameAsSelectedId$, differentFromSelectedId$])
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really promising but my if-else block is different, I am trying to work out how to do based on your example

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `delayWhen` it will delay the stream until its inner observable completes.

```
// this replaces the tap operator in your code
delayWhen(([paramMap, selectedValue]) => {
  const snapshot = this.route.snapshot;
  const categories = snapshot.params.categories;
  
  if (selectedValue && +selectedValue.id === +snapshot.params.selectedId) {
    ...
    this.isLoading = false;
    ...
    // no other observer needed
    return empty();
  } else {
    return this.serviceA.getById(this.route.snapshot.params.selectedId)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(result => this.serviceA.setSelected(result)),
        tap(() => {
          ... 
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
      );
  }
}),
```

never subscribe manually within a stream. rather compose/nest the rxjs operators to one stream and subscribe at one place.